# WPF Converter with parameter from ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to convert the items of a listview with the help of an property in the ViewModel.
I didn't get this to work... the column with the converter is empty
the convert method is never reached. in the output window is following message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ObjectDefinition; DataItem=null; target element
>   is 'OsGuidToNameConverter' (HashCode=66244779); target property is
>   'BindableConverterParameter' (type 'XmlDocument')

the ObjectDefinition is filled at runtime after this message appears

What is the best practise to do that

**xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:OsGuidToNameConverter x:Key="formatter" BindableConverterParameter="{Binding Path=ObjectDefinition}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView Grid.Row="2" Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Config.DocumentTypes}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Objekttyp" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ObjektTyp}"  />
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Bezeichnung">
                <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Value" Converter="{StaticResource formatter}" />
                </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Converter**

```
public class OsGuidToNameConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static DependencyProperty BindableConverterParameterProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("BindableConverterParameter", typeof(XmlDocument),
         typeof(OsGuidToNameConverter));

    public XmlDocument BindableConverterParameter
    {
        get { return (XmlDocument)GetValue(BindableConverterParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BindableConverterParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (BindableConverterParameter is XmlDocument)
        {
            try
            {
                FieldParameter definitionForField = (FieldParameter)ObjectDefinitionHelper.GetObjectDefinitionByAttribute((string)value, SuchFeldTypes.osguid, BindableConverterParameter, SuchFeldTypes.name);
                return definitionForField.Value;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: If I knew that I would correct it. The column is empty. I get no exception

Comment: "The column is empty" still doesn't explain the problem. Did you try placing a breakpoint and debugging your code?

Comment: the Convert method is never reached

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Does the Output window mention any problems with the Binding of the `Value` property.

Comment: no. if I remove the converter I can see the correct (old) value which I want to convert

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the error message

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ObjectDefinition; **DataItem=null**; target element
>   is 'OsGuidToNameConverter' (HashCode=66244779); target property is
>   'BindableConverterParameter' (type 'XmlDocument')

The `DataContext` (`DataItem`) behind your Converter is `null`, so the property `"ObjectDefinition"` cannot be found.

Try moving your converter to `<GridViewColumn.Resources>` so it has the correct `DataContext` for the binding, or switch to an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) which lets you pass in multiple bound values.

A third alternative would also be to pass the entire data item to the `Converter` using `{Binding }`, then cast it to your data type and you can access the `Value` and `ObjectDefinition` properties of it to perform the conversion.

Comment: I tried the MultiConverter but I can't bind the objectdefinition property from ViewModel? The DataContext is Config.DocumentTypes

Comment: ok. with the help of this thread I get this to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786629/wpf-multibinding-in-convertor-fails-dependencyproperty-unsetvalue

Comment: @masterchris_99 Glad you got it sorted out :)